# Inflation Issue in Recycler view

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view in android to show the list of data.I am using link preview also in the view holder class. but my recycler view is not showing any data the page is null.

and its is showing error -

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I have tried many things but not getting any output from there.I have checked my xml file code. which is correct. I have checked the code also but not getting the issue anywhere.

custom row items -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_image_view"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/user_icon"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/post_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Text"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/media_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/jellyfish"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/media_youtube_player_view"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/media_video_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
           />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/media_video_view"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/media_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/video_play_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/video_play_button_black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/link_textView"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="#cdc9c9"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/twitter_link_card_view"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <com.freesoulapps.preview.android.Preview
            android:id="@+id/link_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">

        </com.freesoulapps.preview.android.Preview>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#CFD8DC" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_like_image_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/like_heart_icon"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:focusable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/post_liked_image_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/like_blue_image_icon"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_comment_image_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/comment_icon"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:focusable="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_sharing_imageView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/share_icon"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:focusable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comment_box"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:hint="Type your Comment"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

code for my adapter class -

```
public class AdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> implements  Preview.PreviewListener {
    private List<AllDataModel> allDataArrayList;
    private Context context;
    private int resource;
    Preview linkPreview;
    public  AdapterRecyclerView(TwitterDataTest allDataActivity, int custom_data_main_layout , List<AllDataModel> allDataArrayList) {
        this.context = allDataActivity;
        this.resource = custom_data_main_layout;
        this.allDataArrayList = allDataArrayList;
    }
    public  AdapterRecyclerView(FacebookDataActivity facebookDataActivity, int custom_data_main_layout , List<AllDataModel> allDataArrayList) {

        this.context = facebookDataActivity;
        this.resource = custom_data_main_layout;
        this.allDataArrayList = allDataArrayList;
    }
    public  AdapterRecyclerView(YoutubeDataActivity youtubeDataActivity, int custom_data_main_layout , List<AllDataModel> allDataArrayList) {
        this.context = youtubeDataActivity;
        this.resource = custom_data_main_layout;
        this.allDataArrayList = allDataArrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(resource, parent, false);
        linkPreview =   itemView.findViewById(R.id.link_preview);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {

        final AllDataModel allDataModel = allDataArrayList.get(position);
        //get values from dataModel
        final String username  = allDataModel.getUsername();
        myViewHolder.UserName.setText(allDataModel.getUsername());

        myViewHolder.PostTime.setText(allDataModel.getPost_creation_time());
        String post_time = allDataModel.getPost_creation_time();
        String post_text = allDataModel.getPost_text();
        String status_type = allDataModel.getStatus_type();
        final String link_Title = allDataModel.getLink_title();
        if(status_type != null) {
            Log.e("#444", status_type);
        }

// setting source images
        final String source = allDataModel.getSource();
        String profileimageURL = allDataModel.getProfile_image_url();
        String PostImageURL = allDataModel.getPost_image_url();
        String postThuumbnailImageURL = allDataModel.getPost_video_thumbnail();
        final String videoId = allDataModel.getVideo_id();
        final String VideoUrl = allDataModel.getPost_video();
        final String link_url = allDataModel.getLink_url();
        if(profileimageURL != null){
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(profileimageURL).into(myViewHolder.profileCircularImage);

        }

        if(post_text != null){
            myViewHolder.PostText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.PostText.setText(allDataModel.getPost_text());
        }
        if(PostImageURL !=  null){
            myViewHolder.mediaFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.postMediaImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(PostImageURL).into( myViewHolder.postMediaImage);
        }
        if(postThuumbnailImageURL != null) {
            myViewHolder.mediaFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            myViewHolder.postVideoThumbnailImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(PostImageURL).into( myViewHolder.postMediaImage);
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(postThuumbnailImageURL).into( myViewHolder.postVideoThumbnailImage);
            myViewHolder.play_button_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(videoId != null) {
                myViewHolder.mediaFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myViewHolder.play_button_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        myViewHolder.postMediaImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myViewHolder.play_button_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myViewHolder.postVideoThumbnailImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        Intent youtubePlayerIntent = new Intent((Activity)context, YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
                        youtubePlayerIntent.putExtra("video_id", videoId);
                        context.startActivity(youtubePlayerIntent);

                    }
                }
                );

            }

            if (VideoUrl != null) {
                myViewHolder. play_button_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        myViewHolder.postVideoThumbnailImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myViewHolder.play_button_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        myViewHolder.postVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        try {
                            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
                            mediaController.setAnchorView( myViewHolder.postVideoView);
                            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoUrl);
                            myViewHolder.postVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                            myViewHolder.postVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
                            myViewHolder.postVideoView.requestFocus();
                            myViewHolder.postVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    myViewHolder.postVideoView.start();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Video Play Error :" , e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            if(status_type != null){
                if(status_type.equals("album") || status_type.equals("share") && source.equals("facebook")){
                    Log.e("STA2",status_type);
                    myViewHolder.play_button_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myViewHolder. play_button_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            myViewHolder.postVideoThumbnailImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                            webViewIntent.putExtra("link_url", link_url);
                            context.startActivity(webViewIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

        }

        if(status_type != null){
            if(status_type.equals("share") && source.equals("twitter") && link_Title!=null ){
                myViewHolder.linkCardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myViewHolder.linkPreview.setData(link_Title);
                myViewHolder.linkPreview.setListener((Preview.PreviewListener) this);
                myViewHolder.linkPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent webViewIntent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                        webViewIntent.putExtra("link_url", link_Title);
                        context.startActivity(webViewIntent);
                    }
                });

            }



        }

        myViewHolder.shareutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.share_dialogue);
                dialog.show();
                Button fbShareBtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.share_facebook_button);
                Button twitterShareBtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.share_twitter_button);
                Button cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_share);
                final String link_url = allDataModel.getLink_url();
                fbShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(context, FacebookLoginActivity.class);
                        facebookIntent.putExtra("link_url", link_url);
                        facebookIntent.putExtra("source", source);
                        context.startActivity(facebookIntent);
                    }
                });
                twitterShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent twitterLoginIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                        twitterLoginIntent.putExtra("link_url", link_url);
                        context.startActivity(twitterLoginIntent);
                    }
                });

                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        myViewHolder.postComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myViewHolder.commentET.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        myViewHolder.postLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myViewHolder.postLiked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myViewHolder.postLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        myViewHolder.postLiked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myViewHolder. postLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myViewHolder.postLiked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  allDataArrayList.size();

    }


@Override
public void onDataReady(Preview preview) {
    linkPreview .setMessage(preview.getLink());
}

}
```

code for main activity  -

```
public class TwitterDataTest extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterRecyclerView adapterRecyclerView;
    public List<AllDataModel> allDataArrayList;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_test);
        allDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.twitter_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setTitle("Loading......");
        pd.show();
        if(isOnline()){
            Api apiService =
                    ApiClient.getClient().create(Api.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getTwitterData();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            String s = response.body().string();
                            LoadIntoListView(s);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(TwitterDataTest.this, "No response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(TwitterDataTest.this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(TwitterDataTest.this, R.layout.custom_data_main_layout, allDataArrayList);
         adapterRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);

    }


    public void LoadIntoListView(String s) {
        pd.dismiss();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray1 = new JSONArray(s);
            int ja1length = jsonArray1.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < ja1length; i++) {
                String source = "twitter";
                String videoThumbnailImageUrl = null;
                String TweetVideoUrl = null;
                String TweetImageUrl = null;
                String expanded_url = null;
                String url = null;
                String link_url = null;

                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                //    String TweetTime = jsonObject1.getString("created_at");
                String TweetText = jsonObject1.getString("full_text");
                String id = jsonObject1.getString("id");
                link_url = "https://twitter.com/AmritDki/status/" + id;


                String createdTime = jsonObject1.getString("created_at");
                final String TWITTER = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
                SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER);

                sf.setLenient(true);
                String TwitterCreationDateIST = String.valueOf(sf.parse(createdTime));

                SimpleDateFormat formatter;
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
                String dateIST_customFormat = formatter.format(sf.parse(createdTime));


                if (TweetText.contains("http") == true) {
                    int index = TweetText.indexOf("https");
                    TweetText = TweetText.substring(0, index );
                }
                // user json object
                JSONObject userJO = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("user");
                String UserName = userJO.getString("name");
                String ScreenName = userJO.getString("screen_name");
                String ProfileImageUrl = userJO.getString("profile_image_url_https");



                // getting entities object
                if (jsonObject1.has("extended_entities")) {

                    JSONObject ExtendedEntitiesJO = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("extended_entities");
                    ///////
                    JSONArray MediaJA = ExtendedEntitiesJO.getJSONArray("media");
                    for (int j = 0; j < MediaJA.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject insideMediaJO = MediaJA.getJSONObject(j);

                        if (insideMediaJO.has("video_info")) {
                            videoThumbnailImageUrl = insideMediaJO.getString("media_url_https");
                            JSONObject VideoInfoJO = insideMediaJO.getJSONObject("video_info");
                            JSONArray variantsArray = VideoInfoJO.getJSONArray("variants");
                            JSONObject videoUrlJO = variantsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            TweetVideoUrl = videoUrlJO.getString("url");
                            //allDataArrayList.add(new TwitterDataModel(ProfileImageUrl, UserName,TweetVideoUrl, TweetImageUrl, TweetText));
                            allDataArrayList.add(new AllDataModel(source, UserName, ProfileImageUrl,
                                    TweetText, TweetImageUrl, videoThumbnailImageUrl, TweetVideoUrl, dateIST_customFormat, null,link_url,null, null));
                        } else {
                            TweetImageUrl = insideMediaJO.getString("media_url_https");
                            allDataArrayList.add(new AllDataModel(source, UserName, ProfileImageUrl,
                                    TweetText, TweetImageUrl, videoThumbnailImageUrl, TweetVideoUrl, dateIST_customFormat, null,link_url,null, null));
                        }

                    }
                }

                else{

                    JSONObject entitiesJO = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("entities");
                    if(entitiesJO.has("urls")){
                        JSONArray urlsArray = entitiesJO.getJSONArray("urls");
                        if(urlsArray.length() > 0){
                            JSONObject insideUrlsJO = urlsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            if(insideUrlsJO.has("expanded_url")){
                                expanded_url = insideUrlsJO.getString("expanded_url");
                                allDataArrayList.add(new AllDataModel(source, UserName, ProfileImageUrl,
                                        TweetText, TweetImageUrl, videoThumbnailImageUrl, TweetVideoUrl, dateIST_customFormat,
                                        null,link_url, "share",expanded_url));
                            }

                        }else{
                            allDataArrayList.add(new AllDataModel(source, UserName, ProfileImageUrl,
                                    TweetText, TweetImageUrl, videoThumbnailImageUrl, TweetVideoUrl, dateIST_customFormat,
                                    null,link_url, null,null
                            ));

                        }

                    }
                }
                Log.e("#**", String.valueOf(allDataArrayList.size()));
               // adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(TwitterDataTest.this, R.layout.custom_data_main_layout, allDataArrayList);
              //  adapterRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("parsingError", String.valueOf(e));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem after investing 3-4 hours. I was using the getContext() instead of context (Comes through the constructor)in inflating the layout.Small stupid mistake.